# Does the "Search keywords" exposed filter depend on the core search index?

Tags: 8, views, search

If I create an exposed *Search keywords* filter for a view, does this functionality depend on the core search engine?  Do I need to index the site at admin/config/search/pages for a *Search keywords* filter to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the "Search Keywords" filter depends on the core search engine.